# CompletableFuture, main never exits

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I'm learning Java 8 and more in detail the "CompletableFuture". 
Following this interesting tutorial:
https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/

I wrote the following Java class :

```
package parallels;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;




public class Test {
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0";
    private static final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> webPageLinks= new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<30;i++) {
            webPageLinks.add("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
        }

        // Download contents of all the web pages asynchronously
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> pageContentFutures = webPageLinks.stream()
                .map(webPageLink -> downloadWebPage(webPageLink))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        // Create a combined Future using allOf()
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(
                pageContentFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[pageContentFutures.size()])
                );


        // When all the Futures are completed, call `future.join()` to get their results and collect the results in a list -
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> allPageContentsFuture = allFutures.thenApply(v -> {
            return pageContentFutures.stream()
                    .map(pageContentFuture -> pageContentFuture.join())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        });


    }



    private static CompletableFuture<String> downloadWebPage(String pageLink) {
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getRequest(pageLink),executor);
        return completableFuture;
    } 

    public static String getRequest(String url) {
        System.out.println("getRequest");
        String resp =null;
        try {
            ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
            ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url);
            target.register((ClientRequestFilter) requestContext -> {
                requestContext.getHeaders().add("User-Agent",USER_AGENT);
            });
            Response response = target.request().get();
            resp= response.readEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println(resp);
            response.close();  
            client.close();

            System.out.println("End getRequest");
        }catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }




        return resp;

    }



}
```

*(In order to run that code you need "resteasy-client" library)*

But I don't understand why even when all the responses are collected the main method doesn't terminate...

Did I miss something?
Is there some "complete" method to call anywhere, and if yes where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main method completes, but the program continues running as you have created other threads which are still alive. The best solution is to call [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) on your ExecutorService once you've submitted all your tasks to it.

Alternatively you could create an ExecutorService which uses `daemon` threads (see the [Thread documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html)), or a ThreadPoolExecutor with [allowCoreThreadTimeout(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)), or just call [System.exit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) at the end of your main method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I access to the ExecutorService that is created by CompletableFuture automatically?

Comment: To add to this, there are also 30 `ResteasyClient`s that are left un-`close()`d.

Comment: @SpencerPark Thank you I have modified the code in the question to close the ResteasyClients

Comment: But I still don't understand how to access to the Executor that is created by default and call  the shutdown on it...

Comment: You don't need to worry about shutting down the common pool used by CompletableFutures, it won't block the program exiting. You explicitly create an Executor near the top of your program, and as Spencer points out, implicitly create some through your ResteasyClients. You have to shut these down to end the program.

Comment: I think I got it... Instead of passing an "Executor" to CompletableFuture it is also possbile to pass an "ExecutorService" like that adding the following code at the end of the main mehtod it works: "allPageContentsFuture.thenRun(()->executorService.shutdown());"